# Intro to binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Consider the closed interval $[0,1]$ and define $*$ on $[0,1]$ via $a*b=min[a,b]$. Determine whether $*$ is a binary operation on $[0,1]$.

No formal answer yet -- just throwing ideas around and need help with my scattered thoughts.

Since it is a closed interval $[0,1]$, the minimum for $a$ and $b$ would be $0,1$ as long as $a\neq b$?

Or is there something I am missing... Sorry, we started binary operations today so I am a little unsure on the concepts.

EDIT:

If its a closed interval $[0,1]$, any operation $a,b$ yields cannot be outside the interval(obviously?) Just putting together random thoughts. Again, sorry if its me just stating obvious, rudimentary things.

Comment: There are no occurrences of $a,b$ in $\min [0,1].$ Is this intentional? Or do you mean a * b to be $\min(a,b)$ for any $a,b \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not understanding what you mean. That is what the problem states directly from the book. "via $a*b=min[a,b]$. In other words, take the minimum of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If it says "via a*b = $\min[a,b]$ then you changed definition when you used $0,1$ instead of $a,b$ on the right of definition.

Comment: Ah! I gotcha. Thanks! I totally typo'd that. Sorry!

Comment: Edited. Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing--- Usually the min of $a$ and $b$ is written $\min(a,b)$ (round brackets). Is there any significance to using square brackets? Does the book say what $\min [a,b]$ means? Seems here $[a,b]$ should not mean interval...

Comment: It's not about closed intervals. If $S$ is **any** set of real numbers, then $$a*b=\min(a,b)$$ defines a binary operation on $S$, because the minimum of two numbers **is one of those numbers**. To put it more pedantically, $$a*b=\min(a,b)\in\{a,b\}\subseteq S.$$

Comment: It says "consider the closed interval $[0,1]$."

Comment: Thanks, @bof. That was my intuition but I just don't have any confidence in myself when trying to state things.